# Ruby on Rails - How to manage multiple access to shared file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io, concurrency, read-write

I am quite new to Rails and I need to implement a project for my University. This project consists of a website that will use a binary file as database.

So I need to know a thread safe way to read and write this file, taking into consideration that the same file (database) will be used by multiple process (each time someone access the site, it should read and write data into the file).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There really *isn't* a graceful way to handle that. You're much better off taking a more traditional approach, with a SQL server like [mySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), which do basically that same thing.

Edit:

I didn't realize you could [use sqlite in multi-threaded mode](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html). That would seem to satisfy both requirements...

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brad but I think I wasn't enough clear.

I need to implement a kind SQLLite. I cannot use any already done SQL implementation, because I need to implement the sorting and storing methods.

Perhaps it will be way too painfull to work in Rails for that, but I still have some hope :)